# implement a watcher in browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a server on localhost 3000. I want to show the requests coming from a **remote application**

to this server in a **browser** . How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic long polling solution:

1. Record the requests from the remote app on your server (e.g. in a database)
2. Poll with AJAX to fetch any new requests periodically.

Neat HTML5 websockets solution:

1. Setup a websocket between your server and the browser.
2. When a request is made, post message to the client over the websocket.

Maybe checkout http://pusherapp.com for more info on websockets.